Looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction: Harry heals students petrified by basilisk
I'm looking for a fic I read quite a while ago. I don't remember too much, but in the story Harry is able to enter the minds of the students petrified by the Basilisk and 'wake' them up. Each person has a different sort of mindscape. Harry also spends a lot of time in his own mind, and I think is pretty skilled right off the bat at being a legitimens?
It might have been on fanfic.net or ao3 I'm not too sure.

I think this was a subplot of "the Rigel Black chronicles"

I believe this is "The Purebred Pretense", the first book in "The Rigel Black Chronicles".
According to this it is not a Basilisk, but a " a mysterious sickness [that] spreads through the younger years, infecting students' minds and putting them into magical comas". RB/HP saves them by indeed "use her own core as a backdoor out of her own mind, giving her limited awareness of her surroundings. She then connects to Draco's core and uses it as a backdoor into his mindscape."
